# strange : 2 php version on the same server

Tags: php, debian, migration, upgrade, magento

I need to upgrade php 5.4 to 5.6 to use my framework magento 2.
I apply these commands :

> `echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list
>   echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list
>   wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg -O- | apt-key add - 
>   apt-get update
>   apt-get install php5-cli php5-fpm`

It works I have that now in SSH :

```
# php -v
PHP 5.6.30-1~dotdeb+7.1 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2017 14:50:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

But Magento 2 does not works and when I put echo phpversion(); in the index.php, I have this version !
5.4.45-0+deb7u5

I am on debian and I do not understand how I can have 2 other php versions on the same server

Can you help me ?

**EDIT:**

Content of /etc/apache2/mods-available :

```
actions.conf          deflate.conf               php5_cgi.load.dpkg-remove
actions.load          deflate.load               php5.conf
alias.conf            dir.conf                   php5.conf.dpkg-new
alias.load            dir.load                   php5.load
asis.load             disk_cache.conf            php5.load.dpkg-new
auth_basic.load       disk_cache.load            proxy_ajp.load
auth_digest.load      dump_io.load               proxy_balancer.conf
authn_alias.load      env.load                   proxy_balancer.load
authn_anon.load       expires.load               proxy.conf
authn_dbd.load        ext_filter.load            proxy_connect.load
authn_dbm.load        file_cache.load            proxy_ftp.conf
authn_default.load    filter.load                proxy_ftp.load
authn_file.load       headers.load               proxy_http.load
authnz_ldap.load      ident.load                 proxy.load
authz_dbm.load        imagemap.load              proxy_scgi.load
authz_default.load    include.load               reqtimeout.conf
authz_groupfile.load  info.conf                  reqtimeout.load
authz_host.load       info.load                  rewrite.load
authz_owner.load      ldap.conf                  setenvif.conf
authz_user.load       ldap.load                  setenvif.load
autoindex.conf        log_forensic.load          speling.load
autoindex.load        mem_cache.conf             ssl.conf
cache.load            mem_cache.load             ssl.load
cern_meta.load        mime.conf                  status.conf
cgid.conf             mime.load                  status.load
cgid.load             mime_magic.conf            substitute.load
cgi.load              mime_magic.load            suexec.load
charset_lite.load     negotiation.conf           unique_id.load
dav_fs.conf           negotiation.load           userdir.conf
dav_fs.load           php5_cgi.conf.dpkg-new     userdir.load
dav.load              php5-cgi.conf.dpkg-new     usertrack.load
dav_lock.load         php5_cgi.conf.dpkg-remove  vhost_alias.load
dbd.load              php5_cgi.load.dpkg-new
```

Content of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled :

```
alias.conf            autoindex.load  mime.conf         setenvif.conf
alias.load            cgi.load        mime.load         setenvif.load
auth_basic.load       deflate.conf    negotiation.conf  ssl.conf
authn_file.load       deflate.load    negotiation.load  ssl.load
authz_default.load    dir.conf        php5.conf         status.conf
authz_groupfile.load  dir.load        php5.load         status.load
authz_host.load       env.load        reqtimeout.conf
authz_user.load       expires.load    reqtimeout.load
autoindex.conf        headers.load    rewrite.load
```

Comment: Take a look at which version of PHP Apache is configured for.  Check in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled vs. what is in mods-available, and a2enmod/a2dismod as needed

Comment: in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load :
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
In /mods-available/php5.load 
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so

Comment: The content of the actual file will be the same between mods-available and mods-enabled - the enabled are just symlinks back to -available.  But if you get a directory listing, are there any other php related modules in -available?  Alternatively use dpkg to show a listing of what files the php56 package(s) own

Comment: I add folder content in top subject, I think there is php5_cgi and php5
But I do not know which one I must delete and how

Comment: Gentoo allows to have different PHP versions on a single server, just saying :)

Comment: yes but i want just 1 version the 5.6

Answer (score 0):

In default installation, php is **installed as apache-module**. 
e.g. package libapache2-mod-php5

other possibilities to include php to apache could be cgi, fast-cgi, fcgid... (here you have to search in the *cgi*-config for the path to the php-binary. But I guess you are using php as apache module so check the following.

search for php-packages:

```
# dpkg -l | grep php
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                      5.6.29-1~dotdeb+7.1 [...]
```

if you have not this version number, **check if the package is installed from the dotdebian-repository**. (the default selected version for install is marked with *** before the version number)

You could check from which repository a package would be installed with apt-cache.

```
# apt-cache policy libapache2-mod-php5
```

Installing a package from an explicit repository could be done with the -t switch

```
# apt-get -t wheezy-php56 install libapache2-mod-php5
```

**what about the php on commandline?**

when you run "php" on commandline another binary is executed.

find out which binary is used and which packaged installed it:

```
# dpkg -S $(readlink -f $(which php))
php5-cli: /usr/bin/php5
```

In this example, the package php5-cli ships the binary used when typing "php" in the console.